# Read Json file - Define readJSON file variable

Tags: jenkins

I need to get the content of a Json file in each of the pipeline stages. 
Is there any way to declare "variables" without having to define in each of the stages?

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
        stage('Read Json Stage 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Read Json Stage 1'
                    def variables = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/jenkins/Jenkins_Variables.json"
                    echo "${variables.path_version1}"
                }
            }
        }        
        stage('Read Json Stage 2') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Read Json Stage 2'
                    def variables = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/jenkins/Jenkins_Variables.json"
                    echo "${variables.path_version2}"
                }
            }
        }       
        stage('Read Json Stage 3') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Read Json Stage 3'
                    def variables = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/jenkins/Jenkins_Variables.json"
                    echo "${variables.path_version3}"
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can remove `def` to assign variables to the script binding. If you want to ensure variable type, declare variable before the `pipeline` section.

Comment: @zett42 I cannot do that because "${WORKSPACE}" only could be instantiate inside pipeline.

Comment: Create an "Initialize" stage then.